# How to write a timer algorithm for energy refill games

Tags: timer, countdown, energy

Similar to Tetris on Facebook, where if you're at 100 Energy, after usage (playing a game), it goes down 5 units, and the recharges 1 unit every 10 minutes.  I'm curious how to handle polling, and possibly making it server-side so that there's no "time manipulation" (e.g setting the clock forward in the future) to circumvent measures for receiving energy early.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using?  What is the environment you will be running in?  Is this going to be a Facebook app or something else?  Please give more information so that we may better assist you. A [sscce](http://sscce.org) is always good to have.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of persistent infrastructure, and ideally you want to run a check against the server from the client side, just have it return a JSON string with the value whenever it loads. Also, don't use the client clock, because that could change across machines etc. which would not yield the ideal results.